# React-native-voice-changer works with IOS?

Tags: react-native, voice

I want to use the react-native-voice-changer package for my application, but when I looked at the files, it did not contain the IOS directory. Since there is no information about it, could someone tell me if it is possible to use it for IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now the package support only Android, i'll work later to publish an IOS version for it.